# Concatenate variable names (inside loop)

Tags: r, concatenation

In my data.frame I want to add automatically some variabeles inside a loop. For instance "abc_1", "abc_2", "abc_3".

data.frame:

```
x <- c(1,2,3)
y <- c(4,5,6)
test<- data.frame("V1"=x, "V2"=y)
```

formula to create new variables:

```
for (i in 1:3){
  paste("test$abc",i,sep="") <- 5
}
```

Maybe the loop isn't the best method, but ok. So on the left side of the formula in the loop I try to concatenate 3 variables based on the "i" and some text. But paste doesn't work. Anybody got a bether idea?

Comment: Perhaps you need `[` or may be `test[paste0("abc", 1:3)] <- 5`

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Still figuring out how and when to use brackets;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do this without a `for` loop

```
test[paste0("abc", 1:3)] <- 5
```